# extjs panel resize while window resizes

Tags: extjs, resize, panel

I have a panel with a "form" layout, containing several buttons. now I want to enable this panel resize according to window resizing. How can I get this done?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the panel resizable by setting the 'resizable' config option, see the docs for the various options: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.panel.Panel.html.

As far as how the form components interact you'll need to set anchor's if you want to use a form layout or switch to an hbox/vbox type of set-up with various flex settings.

Answer (score 13):

```
Ext.EventManager.onWindowResize(function(w, h){
    panel.doComponentLayout();
});
```

Assuming you have a Panel named 'panel' with some automatic sizing built in (e.g. `height: "100%"`). Otherwise, the new width and height of the window are passed into the anonymous function passed to `onWindowResize()`.

Comment: Thank you. This post helped me with a completely different problem.

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for! I had to resize a window, so I simply passed the anonymous functions height and width to the setSize function. `window.setSize(w, h)`

Comment: In ExtJS 6 EventManager is deprecated, so use the **Ext.GlobalEvents** instead:  `Ext.GlobalEvents.on('resize', function(w, h) { ... });`

Answer (score 5):

As wrote @deniztt you should subscribe to EventManager class onWindows Resize Event.

It can be something like this:

```
Ext.EventManager.onWindowResize(function () {

    var width = Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width - 160;
    var height = Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height - 140;

    panel.setSize(width, height);

});
```

Where panel is reference to your panel

You can  [**read about it here**](http://myextjs.blogspot.com/2011/11/resize-window-resize-grid.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the size for window and set the child panel's `autoHeight` and `autoWidth` attributes true.
Another way is catching the `resize` event of the window and resize the child panel according to the new size values.

Comment: autoWidth and autoHeight don't seem to work in a chart context. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if there is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Gegory and Joseph for the EventManager solution. I've done some minor changes to this solution, replacing the getBody() with a DIV and setting an initial width/height of my chart (or any other component):

```
<div id="chart" style="overflow: hidden; position:absolute; width:100%; height:90%;"></div>
....
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var renderDiv = Ext.get('chart_div');
    var chart = Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
        renderTo: renderDiv,
        width: renderDiv.getWidth(),
        height: renderDiv.getHeight() - 50,
        ...
    });

    Ext.EventManager.onWindowResize(function () {
        var height = renderDiv.getHeight() -50;
        var width = renderDiv.getWidth();
        chart.setSize(width, height);
    });
});
```

autoWidth and autoHeight don't seem to work for me (Ext-JS 4.2.1).