# ExtJs 4 Grid panel not resizing properly on window resizing

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am rendering Grid Panel in a DIV, for both DIV and Grid Panel I have not specified any width so that it should take up all the browser's width available. When browser window is re-sized by user this Grid do not re-size itself as per new width of browser. I have already tried suggestion / solutions I found in below links, but these are not working for me

[Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885868/extjs-panel-resize-while-window-resizes) - From this I tried on window re-size solution

[ExtJs Plugin - Fit to parent](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?28318-Fit-to-parent) - I also ported this ExtJs 3 plugin to ExtJs 4, but this also didn't helped

Any pointer or help is highly appreciated

Here is code snippet of Grip panel form my project

```
    Ext4.define('myNameSpace.myGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext4.grid.Panel',
    alias: ['widget.myGrid'],
    constructor: function (config) {
        config = Ext4.apply({}, config || {}, {
            columnLines: true,
            sortableColumns: false,
            enableColumnHide: false,
            enableColumnMove: false,
            enableColumnResize: false,
            forceFit: false,
            viewConfig: {
                enableTextSelection: true,
                stripeRows: false,
                loadMask: false,
                emptyText: '<div class="x-grid-empty"> NO Data present</div>',
                deferEmptyText: true,
                getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, rowParams, store){
                    return record.data.isExpired ? "expired-transaction" : '';
                }
            },
            columns: {
                defaults: { 
                    height: 30  
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        text: "&#160;",
                        id: "recurringColumnHdr",
                        width: 30,
                        dataIndex: "isRecurring",

                        align: "center"
                    },
                    {
                        text: "From",
                        id: "fromColumnHdr",
                        width: 175,
                        flex: .15,
                        dataIndex: "fromAccountDescription"
                    },
                    {
                        text: "To",
                        id: "toColumnHdr",
                        width: 175,
                        flex: .15,
                        dataIndex: "toAccountDescription"
                    },
                    {
                        text: "Amount",
                        id: "amountColumnHdr",
                        width: 100,
                        dataIndex: "amount",
                        renderer: Ext4.util.Format.usMoney,
                        align: 'right'
                    },
                    {
                        text: "Date",
                        id: "dateColumnHdr",
                        width: 75,
                        dataIndex: "transferDate",
                        align: 'right'

                    },
                    {
                        text: "Repeat",
                        id: "repeatColumnHdr",
                        dataIndex: "frequency",
                        flex:.35,

                    },
                    {
                        text: "Memo",
                        dataIndex: "memo",
                        id: "memoColumnHdr",
                        flex: .35
                    }
                ]
            },
            dockedItems: [{
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                dock: 'bottom',
                height: 30
            }]
        });
        this.callParent([config]);



    }
});
```

Here is code which I am using to render above grid

```
 Ext4.create('myNameSpace.myGrid', {
            store: Ext4.create('myGridStore'),
            renderTo: 'transfersGrid',
            id: "transferGridPanel"
        });
```

Comment: Not enough code...all you provided is the grid definition but not how or where you are rendering it in relation the the rest of the HTML on the page.  You have defined a component but where is the create code?

Comment: @bakamike -  I have added rendering code for this grid. Actually this code is part of bigger project, hence its difficult to give detailed code. Let me know in case you actually want to see complete HTML, in that case I will pull it from browser and take out relevant HTML. Even if you can give some pointer to fix this issue I will try to take it further. Thanks for your help

Comment: Got this fix - issue was with some other surrounding HtML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this fixed, there was issue with other surrounding HTML and not with grid

Answer (score 0):

Use minWidth, maxWidth, minHeight and maxHeight properties in grid config

Comment: Got fixed for this, issue was with other surrounding HTML and not with actual grid