# Ext.js: Resizing Panel on Browser Resize

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I have a side panel that uses Ext.js.  One of the panels within the side panels is fine until the browser resizes. Upon browser resize, it cuts off components of the panel.

[image: Cut off]

How can I make the panel resize upon browser resizing?

```
{
        xtype: 'panel',
        border: 1,
        margin: 5,
        flex: 1,
        autoScroll: true,
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: localization.moduleS.labelOutlineAttributesField,
                border: 0,
                bodyPadding: '12 5 12 5',
                className: 'outlineAttrField',
                hidden: true,
                items: [
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'sattrfillinpanel',
                title: localization.moduleS.labelFillInAttributesField,
                border: 0,
                bodyPadding: '2 5 12 5',
                hidden: true
            },
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: localization.moduleS.labelGeoAttributesField,
                border: 0,
                bodyPadding: '5',
                className: 'outlineField',
                hidden: true,
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'sdrawbuttonpanel',
                        className: 'drawButtonPanel',
                        margin: '0 0 0 0', 
                    }, 
                    {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        title: localization.moduleS.labelFiltersPanel,
                        border: 0,
                        margin: '0, 5, 0, 2',
                        className: 'filtersField',
                        hidden: true,
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'sfeaturefilterpanel',
                                className: 'baseMapOutlineField',
                                label: localization.moduleS.labelShowAttributesOnLeftField
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'sfeaturefilterpanel',
                                margin: '0 0 0 0',
                                className: 'dualMapOutlineField',
                                label: localization.moduleS.labelShowAttributesOnRightField
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                ]
            },
```

The filters field is what's getting cut off

Comment: Potential dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885868/extjs-panel-resize-while-window-resizes

Comment: @SenseiJames The `resizable` property let's the user click and drag to resize. That's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for the box to just elongate by itself.

Comment: There's not enough information here, you have all the custom xtypes that mask what's happening inside them. Also, it's important to show the whole layout hierarchy. I'd suggest putting together a minimal test case to reduce the cruft (the hidden panels don't seem relevant, for example).

Comment: Also, what Ext version?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli 4.1.1. The panels are hidden upon the loading of the site, but then set to not be hidden later.  So the panels having the issues are `baseMapOutlineField` and `dualMapOutlineField`.  I can try adding more code, just not entirely sure what to add. I'm pretty new to ext.js

Comment: That's what I mean, I don't know the layouts/contents of those custom xtypes because you didn't post them. You should create a runnable example with minimal code that demonstrates the issue: http://fiddle.sencha.com

Comment: Do you have the Ext.container.Viewport as root container? Or you use renderTo property of Ext.Panel to place it inside of some HTML element, that seized by your CSS?

I think that something broke ExtJS layout, if you have Viewpoer. And if you use render to HTML, you should just add event on window resize and manage size of panel manualy from listener of evetn by call method setSize.

Comment: @Selmaril I'm using ViewPort as the root. What would break the ExtJS layout?

Comment: @tibsar maybe you can see errors in debugger console after resize? It's will mean, that some error stop calculation of layout. If not, then it's more difficult case. I need more code to detect problem. It's can be wrong layout type. Maybe you can post full page that will work? Or post some code in https://fiddle.sencha.com/? Maybe post archive with one working page?

Comment: You won't get a good answer without posting the relevant information. You haven't posted the layout structure above the snippet you posted. You also didn't post the layout of how that inner component is laid out, all we know it's some custom xtype. Make a working example.

Comment: have you tryed to set a flex to the components inside the panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not on your panel resizing, I think your code is correct, but in my opinion the problems are in inside panel's components.

Personally if I'm using a vbox or hbox layout inside a panel I set to the components inside it a flex value, obviously on resize event of the browser your components can't, without a flex, resize automatically.

try just to put a flex to your components.

here examples about use of layouts that helped me in the past:
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html

using a viewport, with a panel inside it and a vbox layout, setting flex values, i always had the resizing i expected.

sometimes you need to refresh your components layout in case of massives changes

Comment: Okay! I'll try it!